# Passing custom EventArgs as parameter of event

Tags: c#, .net, events

I am new to events and have been trying to create one and succeed but I have one question.

I have created event like this:

```
public class CustomControl : Panel
{
    public event EventHandler OutputChanged; //My event

    public CustomControl()
    {
        InitializeComponents();            
    }

    //This event raises inside richtextbox which is inside my panel
    private void OnTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (OutputUpdate == OutputUpdate.OnTextChanged)
        {
            ValidateText();
            //This is my created event
            OnOutputChanged(new OutputChangedEventArgs { Asd = "Something" });
        }
    }

    //void for this event
    protected virtual void OnOutputChanged(OutputChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler handler = OutputChanged;
        if(handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
}

//Custom event args class for my event
public class OutputChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Asd { get; set; }
}
```

Above code shows declaration of my event with custom class for `EventArgs` parameter and now I will show you how I implement it in my code:

```
customControl1.OutputChanged += OnOutputChanged;

private void OnOutputChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OutputChangedEventArgs args = e as OutputChangedEventArgs;
    MessageBox.Show(args.Asd);
}
```

As you can see in my implantation I pass `EventArgs` and then I convert it to `OutputChangedEventArgs` and reason for that is because if I try `private void OnOutputChanged(object sender, OutputChangedEventArgs e)` I get error `No overload for 'OnOutputChanged' matches delegate 'EventHandler'`

So my question is how can I directly pass my custom `EventArgs` class so I do not need to convert it inside method that handles it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the generic version of `EventHandler` that allows the specification of the argument type.

```
public event EventHandler<OutputChangedEventArgs> OutputChanged;
```